# DllRegisterServer entry point was not found Error

Tags: dll

I'm trying to register a dll on a XP box and when I run regsvr32 interop.progname.dll I get the following error message:  "interop.progname.dll was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found.  This file can not be registered."

Anybody know how to fix that?

EDIT:
I figured it out.  I was trying to register the wrong file.  <sheepishgrin />

Comment: You could delete the question.

Comment: why? someone else may do the same stupid thing and this could save them time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is accurate, if not completely clear. regsvr32 does its stuff by loading the DLL into memory, then calling the DLLRegisterServer function defined in the DLL.

If the DLL doesn't have a DLLRegisterServer function, then you get that error about the function being missing.

If ever you're in doubt, the depends.exe tool can show you what functions are defined in the DLL.

Which, as you've already seen, happens when you try to regsvr32 a DLL that isn't a COM server of some kind.