# regsvr32 error: DllRegisterServer entry point was not found

Tags: dll

I'm triying to register "Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll" in my Windows 2003 Server but when execute the regsvr32 command i have this error:

"Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found. This file can nto be registered."

How i can register this dll?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/25851/dllregisterserver-entry-point-was-not-found-error/25880#25880). Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm afraid not :_(

In this message the user was using a wrong path to the dll file. In my case i'm copiying directly the full path from window explorer.

Comment: To install Office PIAs you need to install Office 2003.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/02a11067-10dd-4d87-9469-db3be44f5066/

Answer (score 2):

It might be because the dll doesn't have a DllRegisterServer entry point.

This is a .NET dll, NOT a COM dll, and so you *don't* regsvr32 it.  Instead you need to install the Visual Studio Tools for Office from e.g. [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=5E86CAB3-6FD6-4955-B979-E1676DB6B3CB&displaylang=en).